# Homomorphism between cyclic groups of order 4 and 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, group-homomorphism

I need to show that there is an homomorphism between cyclic groups of order 4 and 2. Its the first time I'm studying group theory so I'm fairly confused about what i need to do here. My attempt was the following:

I need to show that there is a map $\varphi : \mathcal{G} \to \mathcal{H}$ that preserves the group multiplication, where $\mathcal{G}$ is a cyclic group of order 2 and $\mathcal{H} $ a cyclic group of order 4. So i attempet to define the map as follows:
$$
\mathcal{G}=\{ x^0=e, x^1\}; \space\mathcal{H}=\{y^0 , y^1, y^2,y^3\}\\
\varphi:\mathcal{G}\to\mathcal{H}\\
\varphi(x^n)=y^{2n}
$$
Witch preserves group multiplication since:
$$
\varphi(x^nx^m)=\varphi(x^{n+m})=y^{2(n+m)}=y^{2n}y^{2m}=\varphi(x^n)\varphi(x^m)
$$
Honestly i doubt this makes much sense so i decided to ask about it here. Any clarifications are much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that because elements in finite cyclic group have more than one way to be expressed (eg. In $\mathcal{G}$, $x^5=x^1$). You have to show that the map is well-defined, that is, for integers $p,q$, $x^p=x^q$ implies that $\varphi (x^p)=\varphi(x^q)$. This can be proven as follows:

Since $x^p=x^q$, we have $x^{p-q}=1$ and therefore $2$ divides $p-q$. This implies that $4$ divides $2(p-q)=2p-2q$. It follows that $y^{2p-2q}=1$, i.e., $y^{2p}=y^{2q}$ and therefore we prove that $\varphi (x^p)=\varphi(x^q)$.

Comment: The proof is not completely fine then. And I find "You might have to show" misleading. You totally have to show this, at least if you want to use the formula $\phi(x^n) = y^{2n}$ not just for $n = 0$ or $n=1$. I think this was exactly the problem in the proof (and the source of the hesitation about it). One other way to write this would be something like: $\phi(x^{n+2}) = \phi(x^nx^2) = \phi(x^n)y^4= \phi(x^n)$, so $\phi(x^n)$ depends only on the parity of $n$.

Comment: @J.Darné Correction done. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You're welcome. Your answer was the best one, it only needed this slight improvement to become a fine one ;)

Answer (score 1):

Or, you could do an inclusion homomorphism,  since $\mathbb Z_4$ contains a copy of $\mathbb Z_2$ as a subgroup. Actually,  that's the same one as $h (x)=2x $.  There's only one nontrivial way to do it,  because a homomorphism out of a cyclic group is determined by where it sends $1$, say.  And the only nontrivial place to send it is to $2$, since the order of $h (1) $ must divide  $2$.